# A question about the limit of a sequence of uniformly bounded armonic functions

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Given an open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, a sequence of armonic functions $\{u_n\} \subseteq \Omega$ that are uniformly bounded on every compact set of $\Omega$ and that are supposed to reach almost everywhere a limit function $u$, what can we can say about the continuity of $u$?

Comment: By [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball) the sequence is equicontinuous. By Ascoli ...

Comment: I can't get were you are taking me. I do not know what equicontinous funtion are and I do not know any Ascoli theorem. Can you please add more details or quote a reference?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces) should get you started. The situation with harmonic functions is very similar to [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem).